# Variable img is both not defined and unused — why is that?

Tags: c, struct

I have this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        struct ppm* img = ppm_read(argv[1]);
    }
    else
        error_exit;
    find_msg(img);
}
```

and for unknown reasons (to me), the compiler complains like

```
 warning: unused variable img
```

to `img` in 'if' condition, and also

```
error: 'img' undeclared
```

in `find_msg(img)` function.

Why?

Comment: The scope of the declaration of `struct ppm* img` is limited to the if-clause body.

Comment: You need to indent your code properly. Poorly indented code likes your's is hard to read, hard to understand and hard to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out in comments, the `img` variable goes out of scope at the `}` after it is defined.  It isn't used while it is defined — hence the 'unused variable' warning.  It isn't available after the `}` — hence the 'undeclared variable' warning.

Assuming `error_exit` is a macro that exits the program somehow, then you should probably write:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        error_exit;

    struct ppm* img = ppm_read(argv[1]);
    find_msg(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to declare the object outside of the if statement, then assign it a value inside the if statement. Here’s some more information on scope rules. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/amp/